# Reasons for Detached HTMLDivElements in React app

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, redux, react-redux

I've been debugging a memory issue in the Memory Profiler for a React/Redux App and I've noticed these `Detached HTMLDivElements` along with a few other types of elements.

[image]

I'm not using a typical navigation library just using state to move screens around.  I'm not sure if this is an issue with Chrome and it's Garbage Collector or React and somehow holding a reference to old screens.

What reasons would there be for a React app to keep these Detached Elements.  Could redux `connect()` potentially hold a reference to the store causing the component to not get recycled?

Lastly, I should say this is a React/Redux app as a Chrome Extension.

---

Digging into the issue I've noticed that the class `Messenger` (the root component that holds the chat messaging logic) is listed 3 times in the Memory Profiler.

[image]

And here's how I've structured screens.

```
renderScreen = () => {

   switch (this.state.screen) {
      case Screen.HOME:
         return <Home/>
      case Screen.MESSENGER:
         return <Messenger/>
      ....

   }
}

render() {
   ...
   return this.renderScreen()

}
```

Does this mean that a new class `Messenger` is created every time it navigates to that component?